# Get first url segment

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How would I go about changing the default `controller/action` and `RouteConfig.cs` so that I always display the first url segment on the page?

So if the url is `mysite.com` the page should be blank, if it is `mysite.com/somepage` I should get `somepage` printed on the page, if the page is `mysite.com/services` I should get `services` printed on the page and so on.

The default controller is `Home` and the default method action is `Index`.

I guess the method would go something like this:

```
public ActionResult Index(string page = "")
        {
            return Content(page);
        }
```

But what about `RouteConfig.cs` ?

Comment: `routes.MapRoute("Home", {page}, new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });` but this means you will never be able to have any other routes - the only method you can ever navigate to is `mysite.com/someValue` unless you create specific routes for all you other controller methods before this one

Comment: That seems to be what I am looking for (in theory). however I get an error in the code: 'The name page does not exist in the current context'

Comment: What code cause that error? (its not due to anything your have shown in the question)

Comment: Managet to get it working with your help and an answer from another question. {user} should be a string.

Answer (score 1):

You should erase the default route and add your custom ones, like this:

```
// Home route
routes.MapRoute("Home", "", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
```

The second parameter in routes.MapRoute is the url, which in this case is empty. For services you would have your route like this:

```
// Services route
routes.MapRoute("Services", "services", new { controller = "Some Controller", action = "Some action" });
```

Comment: I erased the default one, added your one and if I go e.g. to mysite.com/test I get `HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found` instead of `test`. My Index method is like the one from the Q.

Comment: What do you mean, mysite.com/Home or mysite/Home/Index? That doesn't work. Whatever I append to the main url does not work.

Comment: I mean mysite.com should route to your home

Comment: Yes, I get a blank page (as I expect).

Comment: and how did you map your route to "test"?

Comment: I didn't, as I said in the Q I want to get the first segment regardless of what it is and display it on the page, not hardcode the route.

Comment: well, if you don't want to end up with lots of custom routes, one easy way is to use attribute routing. Update this custom route that I wrote to: routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes(); . Then on the top of your action method you can add the Route annotation. For instance, for your home route: [Route("")] and on top of your test action method: [Route("test")]. Get it?